# When should a BLE central iOS app read an encrypted characteristic?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an iOS app which is a central to a peripheral on which I control the firmware. A similar Android app works fine and is able to connect to the peripheral, discover services, bond explicitly, and read an encrypted characteristic.

On iOS, however, there is no explicit bonding in the CoreBluetooth API. I am working on the basis that if I want to bond, I should just read an encrypted characteristic in order to force bonding to occur.

When is the right time to do that? If I do it when discovering the characteristic I want to read, in this function...

```
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService service: CBService!, error: NSError!)
```

... I never get a callback to peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic. Reading an unencrypted characteristic at this point does work though, I believe.

[EDIT]

Here's the code for my CBPeripheralDelegate implementation.

```
import CoreBluetooth
import CoreLocation

class BluetoothPeripheralController: NSObject, CBPeripheralDelegate {

    private var _peripheral: CBPeripheral!
    var peripheral: CBPeripheral! {
        get {
            return self._peripheral
        }
        set {
            if self._peripheral != nil {
                self._peripheral = nil
            }

            self._peripheral = newValue

            if self._peripheral != nil {
                self.peripheralDidChange(newValue)
            }
        }
    }

    private var notificationCenter: NSNotificationCenter = {
        return NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    }()

    private var testModeCharacteristic: CBCharacteristic?

    private var voltageCharacteristic: CBCharacteristic?

    private var firmwareLoggingCharacteristic: CBCharacteristic?

    static let voltageDidChangeNotification = "voltageDidChangeNotification"

    static let testModeDidChangeNotification = "testModeDidChangeNotification"

    static let bonded = "bonded"

    static let firmwareLoggingDidChangeNotification = "firmwareLoggingDidChangeNotification"

    func peripheralDidChange(peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        peripheral.delegate = self
    }

    func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didDiscoverServices error: NSError!) {
        if error != nil {
            log.error("Error: \(error)")
            return
        }

        for service in peripheral.services {
            log.verbose("Discovering characteristics for service: \(BleService().lookup(service.UUID))")

            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, forService: service as! CBService)
        }
    }

    // Hold on to characteristic instances so we can read/write/notify on them later.
    func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService service: CBService!, error: NSError!) {
        if let chars = service.characteristics as? [CBCharacteristic] {
            log.verbose("* \(BleService().lookup(service.UUID))")

            for char in chars {
                log.verbose("** \(BleCharacteristic().lookup(char.UUID))")

                if char.UUID.isEqual(BleCharacteristic.voltageCharacteristicUUID) {
                    voltageCharacteristic = char
                }

                if char.UUID.isEqual(BleCharacteristic.testModeCharacteristicUUID) {
                    testModeCharacteristic = char

                    log.verbose("Reading value for test mode.")

                    // Reading any encrypted value here does NOT result in a callback to peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic.
                    peripheral.readValueForCharacteristic(char)
                }

                if char.UUID.isEqual(BleCharacteristic.nordicNrfUartRxUUID) {
                    firmwareLoggingCharacteristic = char
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic!, error: NSError!) {
        if error != nil {
            log.verbose("Error on value: \(error)")
            return
        }

        let data: NSData = characteristic.value

        log.verbose("Got value \(data) for characterisitc \(BleCharacteristic().lookup(characteristic.UUID))")

        switch characteristic.UUID {
        case BleCharacteristic.voltageCharacteristicUUID:
            var voltage: Float = 0.0

            data.getBytes(&voltage, length: sizeof(Float))

            log.debug("Voltage: \(voltage)")

            // The map view is interested in this.
            self.notificationCenter.postNotificationName(BluetoothPeripheralController.voltageDidChangeNotification, object: self, userInfo: ["voltage": NSNumber(float: voltage)])

        case BleCharacteristic.testModeCharacteristicUUID:
            log.debug("Test mode: \(data). We are now bonded.")

            self.notificationCenter.postNotificationName(BluetoothPeripheralController.bonded, object: self, userInfo: nil)

        default:
            log.debug("Unknown characteristic UUID: \(characteristic.UUID)")
        }
    }

    func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic!, error: NSError!) {
        if error != nil {
            log.verbose("Error updating notification state: \(error)")
            return
        }

        switch characteristic.UUID {
        case BleCharacteristic.nordicNrfUartRxUUID:
            log.verbose("Notification state change on firmware logging. Now notifying: \(characteristic.isNotifying)")

        default:
            log.verbose("Unhandled characteristic: \(characteristic.description)")
        }
    }

    // Read/write
    func readTestMode() {
        if testModeCharacteristic == nil {
            log.warning("Trying to read test mode before we have a characterisitc instance.")

            return
        }

        // Calls back to peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic.
        peripheral.readValueForCharacteristic(testModeCharacteristic)
    }

}
```

Comment: Issuing a read at that point should trigger bonding. Can you show the code you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the desired characteristic is present in `didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService` using the service's `characteristics` property.

It's up to your peripheral to return an authentication error when you try to read the characterisitc prior to bonding. The error will appear in `didUpdateValueForCharacteristic` if you need to do something with it, but the error alone will trigger the bonding.

From [Bluetooth Accessory Design Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/hardwaredrivers/BluetoothDesignGuidelines.pdf):

> If, for security reasons, the accessory requires a bonded relationship
>   with the Central, the Peripheral should reject the ATT request using
>   the Insufficient Authentication error code, as appropriate.

Comment: The characteristic is there in didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService, for sure. But there's no callback to didUpdateValueForCharacteristic, either initially with an error or later without. This is a characteristic that I can read and write just fine from an Android app.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's OK to read a characteristic value during `peripheral:didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService` and the only reason I wasn't getting my callback was that iOS had cached the bond from earlier, but the peripheral had since had it's own side of that bond wiped.

The solution was either or both of: a) Going to the iOS Settings app and "forgetting" the peripheral and b) Rebooting the phone.